# How to specify multiple includes that are not mandatory altogether

Tags: include, uml, use-case

Let's say I have *three* use cases:

*First* and *second* use cases are simple actions that can't be performed simultaneously. The *third*, though, can only happen while first **OR** second has happened. Do I have to specify this in the model below? If yes, **how?** The model right now gives me impression that the first and second use cases have to be performed **BOTH**(which is not true in the system) in order to perform the third.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to model it using a precondition: "The precondition of a use case announces what the system will ensure is true before letting the use case start". (A. Cockburn, Writing Effective Use Cases, p. 81)

Exactly how you can annotate a precondition depends on your tool. A precondition is typically written down in textual form (human-readable to non-IT stakeholders) or explicitly references another use case.

Advantage: Clean solution. Uncluttered diagram.
Possible disadvantage: You'll only see that in the full documentation.
Possible workaround: Define such if/else related decisions in an activity diagram and refer to that in the use cases with a note / hyperlink.

Comment: I have re-modeled the use case to have `extend` instead of `include`, but this solution looks good too!